# How to make the logging work in GWT projects?

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I tried to search for an answer for at least an hour, tried all the ways I could find but I can't make the damn thing to log anything from server code.
If I use System.out.println() in client classes, the console logs it just fine, but when I try the same in anything server-side, it just doesn't work!

Anyway, the test class is here: http://pastebin.com/e6XgeUuX

For example, I want to log the uploadsFolder value.
I've tried the following, and none of them worked (no output in Eclipse console, not in .gwt-log, nowhere):

```
System.out.println(uploadsFolder.getPath());
GWT.log(uploadsFolder.getPath());
log.info(uploadsFolder.getPath()); // by creating an ordinary java.util.Logger in the body of the class
```

What do I have to do to make it just log anything I want to log? Why doesn't even System.out.println() work??
I'm totally new to this nightmare so I'll need a thorough explanation, not just "read this".

P.S. I'm trying to make an image gallery with this; I've made the front-end, but now I'm trying to make it save the images on the disk, not in memory and for that I need to know if and where it creates the upload folder (I can't find any ways to find out the path of the war folder...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");
```

This always works for me serverside, System.out.println("") also for that matter.

And perhaps there is something wrong with your uploadsFolder object, try appending something before it like:

logger.log("My Path for uploads:"+ uploadsFolder.getPath());

Comment: Neither works for me, that's why I'm asking. Tried making Logger.getLogger("com.gwttest.server"); and logging like this: 
     final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "gwttestproject/images/upload/" + now;
     log.info(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);
     final File uploadsFolder = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);
     log.info(uploadsFolder.getPath());   What could possibly be wrong with the uploadsFolder object here? And it doesn't matter what I log, I could just do log.severe("OMFG!"); and it won't log a thing.

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry, i think the problem is different as in you cannot use java.io.File in GWT. Acutally a lot of java.io is not supported on GWT. You need to use localstorage from html5, i know this library is usefull http://code.google.com/p/gwt-client-storage/ please let me know if it works

Comment: Ok, well, that's another problem. I'm telling you it doesn't log anything, even plain text! It's got nothing to do with the File class.

Comment: It might be eclipse being funny. you could try a few things like restarting eclipse, cleaning+rebuilding the workspace, reinstalling the google plugin, ceating a new sample project with a different gwt version and using system.out.println() there. Other then that i have nothing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

None of these can be used when the code is compiled into JavaScript (GWT.log() is used for HostedMode logging). There is this library [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) that I've had a lot of success with before, it allows you to log to a file via RPC and many other options.

Comment: The question was about logging server-side, not client-side; the latter one worked for me as I described. Server-side code doesn't get compiled into JavaScript. But anyway, I asked this a year ago and it's not actual to me anymore.